# Is my objection to naturalism popular or fringe in contemporary philosophy?

Tags: semantics, naturalism

I have a line of thought that strict naturalism (in the most extreme case, the belief that only particle physics is an accurate description of reality) is self-defeating. I say this because notions like intentionality, reference and semantic truth cannot be expressed in the language of particle physics. Without appealing to intentionality, it's unclear what it would even mean to say claims about particle physics are true and other claims are false. Therefore, in addition to natural facts, there must be something like fregean senses or epistemic norms. Is this considered a serious line of argument in philosophy today?

Comment: Well, I'd say that intentionality, reference, and semantic truth can indeed be expressed in the language of particle physics. You just have to work really hard. It's as difficult as expressing a chair in the language of particle physics; in theory possible, but in practice it's a very long formula.

Comment: I think this is wrong, especially the analogy to a chair. It seems that by the chair analogy you mean that in particle physics you could describe a human using language, but I think this confuses pragmatics and semantics

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Intentionality supervenes on what is happening in a human brain - and what is happening in the brain is in principle describable in terms of the subatomic particles, though this would be very difficult. In principle, therefore, it is possible to talk about intention using particle physics. "I intend to eat that sandwich" corresponds to a particular situation of particles in my brain, which particle physics is capable of describing.

Comment: @NoahMancino If you claim that intentionality... _cannot_ be expressed in the language of particle physics, you should explain why - after defining all those words more precisely. "Without intentionality..." is not an explanation, because it seems circular. It seems to assume the existence of intentionality as a pre-requisite for claims in particle physics, and that existence is not obvious. It's as if you were saying "intentionality exists therefore naturalism is false", but you have to show that intentionality cannot be explained in naturalism.

Comment: "Intentionality supervenes on the human brain."
First, I do not think this is 100% necessary for you point, but as a semantic externalist I would deny it. 
One of the reasons I am looking for literature about this is because it is more of an intuition than a fleshed out argument but here's a simple objection to the idea that intentionality or meaning are reducible:

Say I make a claim about the moon or the set of real numbers. A complete description of my physical state in terms of physics will not involve the moon or the set or real numbers. Therefore, it cannot possibly fix a referent

Comment: @NoahMancino Can't you imagine an experimental process by which a scientist could determine, empirically, what someone is referring to? If aliens landed on Earth and we had to decode their language from scratch, it seems likely we could eventually succeed in determining what they are referring to. This makes reference itself an empirical matter. Of course, to decode the aliens' word for "moon" would likely involve experiments such as pointing at the actual moon, so in this way the referent is included.

Comment: I cannot imagine such a process. Or, rather, I cannot imagine such a process without presupposing intentionality. You can cash out dispositions to point, sure, but dispositions to point are unreliable and it seems that making a claim is not like pointing (pointing can not be true or false, for example).

Comment: @NoahMancino Well, what is reference but a sort of generalized "disposition to point"? If I know all your dispositions of when you will use a certain word and when you won't use it, what is there left for me to learn about what you refer to with the word? The meaning of a word is determined by its use.

Comment: In a sense I agree that meaning is determined by use, but I would like to say meaning is also determined in some sense by how language *ought* to be used. If this is not the case, it seems unintelligible that words have meanings at all. How are we to distinguish between good uses of language (paradigmatically, correct claims) from bad uses (paradigmatically, false claims or ungrammatical ramblings)?

To answer my own original question, I found at least two widely read authors who agree with me: Robert Brandom and John Searle

Comment: @causative, '"I intend to eat that sandwich" corresponds to a particular situation of particles in my brain' This is begging the question, and still doesn't resolve the issue. Even if it's true it doesn't mean that you can describe intentional states using quantum physics.

Comment: There are plenty of opponents to the full-blown concept of reductionism. In fact I would say that scientific reductionism is a much less popular position in the philosophy of science than it was 50 years ago. Some of the objections are due to issues over consciousness and intentionality. Try David Chalmers, "The Conscious Mind", Thomas Nagel, "Mind and Cosmos", Alvin Plantinga, "Where the Conflict Really Lies".

Comment: All belief systems are ultimately self-defeating. People should do more research in to that. Of course, why would they *want* to?

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/#InteNatu might be of some help

Comment: Semantic truth isn't definable for arithmetic on natural numbers, and thus isn't definable in general; see summaries of Tarski's undefinability of semantic truth at [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth/#TarTheTru) and [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem). Your objection makes sense for the 1920s, after the debut of QM but before Gödel and Turing started publishing; you will need to do some reading to update your position.

Comment: @Corbin
Do inferentialist accounts not solve this issue? You do not need to take truth as a primitive to explain intentionality.

Answer (score 6):

#### You seem to be attacking a common strawman of naturalism

What you presented as naturalism (or "strict" naturalism) may be self-defeating, but this is not what naturalism is, according to naturalists. Whether something that no-one believes is self-defeating is generally irrelevant.

[Naturalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalism_(philosophy)) is "the idea or belief that only natural laws and forces (as opposed to supernatural ones) operate in the universe".

This is a dismissal of the supernatural (generally due to a lack of supporting evidence).

It doesn't imply that everything needs to be able to "be expressed in the language of particle physics", and the only people I've ever heard say something similar are people (often theists) who object to naturalism.

For one thing, naturalists typically accept mainstream scientific knowledge from every field, not just the one branch of one field of science that is particle physics. All of that may ultimately boil down to the movement of physics particles, but one could've been a naturalist before we even knew about atoms. The essence of naturalism is not particle physics, it's the natural world. It's just that the best model of the natural world says that every real-world object is made up of such particles.

Beyond that, there seems to be some confusion or disagreement in the question about what it means for something to exist (according to naturalism), and what naturalism entails.

Naturalism isn't incompatible with semantic truth or epistemic norms, because those things don't directly exist in reality, therefore naturalism doesn't make any claim about them.

#### Regarding intentionality, naturalism holds that minds are reducible to natural processes

If you claim that there's some element of the brain/mind that exists outside the natural world, you obviously reject naturalism, and this wouldn't be a counter-argument as much as a claim that naturalism is false.

It is certainly one common view that there is a mind separate from the brain and outside the natural world. Many theistic beliefs (arguably) rely on it. But the fact that people believe something [doesn't mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) that it's true.

It's true that we don't yet exactly know how consciousness comes about from natural processes, but not knowing something [doesn't mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance) the supernatural exists.

> "Without appealing to intentionality, it's unclear what it would even mean to say claims about particle physics are true and other claims are false."

A claim is true if it matches objective reality. A claim is false if it doesn't match objective reality.

We can evaluate the truth value of a claim (to the extent that we can know truth) through e.g. observation and science.

I don't see the need to appeal to intentionality here.

#### Semantic truth does not (directly) exist in reality

Let's say I state that the Moon exists.

The statement itself may exist as thoughts (i.e. electric signals between neurons), as bits in a computer, as soundwaves, etc.

What I made a statement about (i.e. the Moon) may exist or not exist.

The semantic truth of the statement is only a derivation of the existence of the statement and the existence of the applicable parts of reality. The statement is true if and only if it matches reality.

#### Epistemic norms do not (directly) exist in reality.

Epistemic norms are a set of principles for how we evaluate what is and isn't true.

We determined these principles by observing the world, and seeing which principles would correspond most closely and be most consistent with what we observe.

These principles exist as nothing more than thoughts (or as bits in a computer, as soundwaves, etc.). These principles do not exist independently. We came up with them, to allow us to serve some goal (e.g. to tell us what's true, or to allow us to effectively navigate reality).

The principles may be effective at achieving that goal, or it may be ineffective. Similar to semantic truth, the effectiveness wouldn't exist directly, but rather would be a derivation of things that exist (i.e. the principle as a thought, along with real-world objects or laws that the principle may correspond to).

If I say you should believe whatever you see (not a good epistemic norm), what could exist is this principle as a thought, the objects you see and mental processes that correspond to your sense of sight. If you follow this principle, you'd believe in the existence of some things that exist and some things that don't exist. The principle itself doesn't exist outside of that.

Comment: Seems to reduce to: "Truth does not exist, in reality." (Oops, ignore that extra comma...) Very nondual.

Comment: The claim that non material things do not exist is not supported by evidence. It is an assertion of dogma or ideology and thus not naturalistally valid. Science is based on indirect realism and worlds 2 and 3 of Popper and Frege are as well supported by their utility and test ability as matter (world 1) so a consistent naturalist should be a triplest.  Also science needs emergence, and processes, and neither are reducible.

Comment: @Dcleve Both the non-existence and the existence of non-material things is not well-supported by evidence. (And claims of non-material things, e.g. religion, are often explicitly dogmatic, so it's rather ironic ... and exhausting ... to have people claim skepticism of that is dogma.) So, the question is whether it's more reasonable to believe that something exists until it's disproven, or to believe something doesn't exist until it's proven (if it can even be proven). Naturalism says the former. See also: [Russell's teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot).

Comment: @Dcleve I'm not really sure which part of my answer you believe you're responding to. It seems like you basically just want to object to naturalism in general. But I wasn't arguing for naturalism in general, I was addressing the specific objections raised in the question, so your comment doesn't seem all that relevant to my answer.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Read Two Dogmas of empiricism, I think it’s section 9. Quine notes that the evidence and utility based inference to the reality of math and ideas is equally strong as the inference to the reality of matter.  Quine does not make the argument, but it is an easy extension to apply it to consciousness, where experience is MORE supported than either ideas or matter.  This gets one immediately to 3 world triplism.

Comment: * I meant: Naturalism says the *latter*.

Comment: @Dcleve The key word is (directly). Of course concepts/ideas/thoughts exist in one's mind. The question is whether or not they are mind independent. Now given that ideas/thoughts are merely objects in consciousness and consciousness, and consciousness seems to depend on material causes such as the brain, we have good reason to believe they do not exist mind independently.

Comment: The word 'exist' does not have one meaning but several.  I think you need to be careful in your answer to be clear what meaning you use at what point (and of course the original question might be confused about this also).

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not arguing for cartesian dualism. The "supernatural" thing I'm prepared to stick out my neck for is norms which are not reducible to statements about the world. So it's less about thoughts and consciousness and more about propositions

Comment: @Thinkingman -- I assume a glitch in your post, you meant "brain" independent.  James spelled out the evolutionary test case for that, refuting epiphenomenalism.  Mind is an evolved structure -- IE multiple modules in a non-optimized architecture, but then locally optimized to work together.  Evolved structures require natural selection, which only works on causal systems. Popper extended this test case to all Identity Theories, by noting that all functions of mind are also done unconsciously -- we clearly could have been zombies. Independent mental causation on the physical is demonstrated.

Answer (score 5):

Naturalism doesn’t say that everything must be described using particle physics but rather that the cause of everything that exists is natural. Concepts and ideas only exist in an immaterial sense but even they can only be thought about and hence caused by a brain which has material causes.

Comment: Right. It's like my favorite example of levels: this comment I am writing on this computer is not determined by the computer, yet the computer is fully deterministic. Nothing about transistors had anything to do with choosing these words.

Comment: The causal closure of physics is not supported by physics, which as a science is intrinsically open.  This is Hempel’s Dilemma for physicalists.  That ideas are causal is readily verified by every one of us every day.  The dogma of physicalism is contrary to science. It also violates naturalism by banning the indirect inference to reality for any non material hypotheses.  Equating physicalism to naturalism is thoroughly refuted by test.

Comment: Do you have reference for your claim? It sounds *plausible*, but is not how I usually see 'naturalism' defined.

Comment: I found someone who agrees with you, the psychologist Thomas Hardy Leahey say it's "the thesis that no supernatural or non-natural causes are at work at nature". But I don't think it's a universal definition, so your answer should reflect that

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is an argument against extreme naturalism and it’s validity is a mainstream view.

The extreme reductionist thesis you describe is explicitly "scientism", as it holds that all knowledge reduces to science, and explicitly to physics.  The prevailing view among almost all philosophers is that science cannot justify itself, it needs to be justified by the philosophic subfields of logic and epistemology, as a minimum. And physics cannot be done without mathematics, which also is prior to science.

If other knowledges precede physics, and are more fundamental, then yes, it is incoherent to claim that everything reduces to physics, and scientism is therefore incoherent.

As a broader phenomenon, even within science the consensus view today is that other sciences do not reduce to physics.  This has been a growing into a consensus, as the recognition of the failure of a program of pure reductionism became a majority view in the 1990s in philosophy of science, and that majority has expanded since. The explanations for the failure of reductionism point to the irrelevance/orthogonality of higher order structures to any aspect of a substrate.  See SEP's Scientific Reduction article, particularly section 5.

The poster child for the failure of reductionism is explicit in the term multiple realizability -- a function or behavior can be demonstrated with nearly infinite different KINDS of substrates, hence that function or behavior can never be reduced to features of the substrates.

The need for emergence to explain the appearance of entirely new scientific phenomenon as complexity increases, plus the utility of holistic models to explain phenomena that are incomprehensible to reductionism, have further led science to embrace a pluralism of fundamental sciences, and a pluralism of methodologies to investigate them.

And the abandonment of scientism extends the pluralism of knowledge to non-science activates.  This is how far your first objection goes.

Your second objection, intentionality, is a less universally accepted problem even for reductionism.  The majority view in philosophy even among naturalists agrees with your view that reductionism can never explain or characterize consciousness. But a stubborn minority of naturalists still argue for promissory reductionism -- that maybe someday consciousness could be reduced, even if it is not possible today.   Note however, that contra to this minority, the SEP article on reduction explicitly named the inability to reduce consciousness as one of the prime examples of the intrinsic limits of reductionism.  So -- you have a majority view in philosophy supporting this point, but not yet a consensus, due to the stubbornness of the counterarguers.

Naturalism, however, is a flexible term, with multiple variants of meaning and usage.  One can be a committed naturalist, and still accept all of the above as true.  So "refuting naturalism" and "refuting absolute reductive naturalism" are very different things, with the first much harder to do than the second.

Comment: The claim that "everything can be reduced to Particle Physics" cannot be reduced to Particle Physics. So it is self-defeating. Cool. So, is something more fundamental than Mathematics? Or is that the last turtle?

Comment: Most things are reducible, but what  epistemology is arriving at is the realization that not ALL things are reducible, hence we need multiple epistemic heuristics. Emergence, wholism, and process science (not everything is a thing) are also needed to understand our universe.  A pluralism of heuristics means no, neither math nor logic can be an alternate “final turtle”, the turtle series is only part of the story.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your first sentence. Is there a word missing or are they in the wrong order?

Comment: @Barmar thanks.  Edited.

Comment: "Only realize, there is no turtle" I guess?

Comment: "The majority view in philosophy even among naturalists agrees with your view that reductionism can never explain or characterize consciousness" - uhh... citation very much needed (in particular for the "even among naturalists" part). Irreducible consciousness seems highly contrary to everything that naturalism is. Consciousness may be "one of the prime examples of the intrinsic limits of reductionism", but this is because we haven't managed to (fully) explain it ... yet (although we have chipped away at much of it through increased understanding of the brain via psychology and neuroscience).

Comment: "you have a majority view in philosophy supporting [irreducible consciousness], but not yet a consensus" - curious use of "yet" there. In the not-so-distant past, the idea of irreducible consciousness would've been much more compelling. But our increasing body of scientific knowledge have attributed memory, emotion, reasoning, etc. to different parts of the brain, leaving very little for any irreducible "consciousness" to even do. So I'd say the idea of *reducible* consciousness is becoming *more* popular, but is not **yet** the consensus (*due to the stubbornness of the counterarguers*).

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- citation already provided, in the SEP article on scientific reductionism.  A second citation is Kim in Physicalism or Something Near Enough, in which he notes that the majority philosophy of mind view among physicalist philosophers since the mid 1970s has been variants of emergent physicalism.  That is a 50 year consensus that your view: " Irreducible consciousness seems highly contrary to everything that naturalism is.", is explicitly contrary to what naturalist philosophers believe.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- the limitations of reductionism have become apparent across multiple sciences.  Reductionism typically fails when the phenomena is highly complex, or when there is a radical orthogonality between the substrate phenomena and the higher tier phenomena.  Both are overwhelmingly the case with consciousness vs. neurology, consciousness is basically a prototypical case where reduction is extremely implausible.  The one science field I know of where this limitation to reduction has not been accepted is neuroscience, which is an isolated island of dogmatic reductionists.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- Read The Astonishing Hypothesis, and compare its goals with what Neuroscience has accomplished since.  Neruoscience has succeeded in characterizing, with a moderate amount of success, multiple unconscious functions.  It has not achieved basically any progress whatsoever with Chalmer's "hard problem of consciousness".  Success in characterizing the UNCONSCIOUS functions of the brain does not support, in any way, an inference about consciousness.  Instead, the massive failure vs. consciousness has its own inference, that consciousness does not reduce..

Comment: @Dcleve "citation already provided, in the SEP article on scientific reductionism" - you'll have to be more specific. I had a brief look, and it [seems to](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/#ModSciRedMin) have an entire section about reductionism of the mind, which suggests the opposite of what you said. Your claim of an "intrinsic limit" is a very specific claim, that you say is "explicitly named", so I expected that roughly word-for-word, but I can only find the word "intrinsic" used once in that article, in a different context, and I can't find anything similar.

Comment: @Dcleve Consciousness being a "current limit" of reductionism would be much less objectionable than an "intrinsic limit", but also much less noteworthy. Reductionism (appears to) "fail" when the phenomena is highly complex because knowledge in general, and scientific understanding in particular, is incremental, and incrementally gaining an understanding something highly complex is difficult and takes a lot of time. It's a practical issue long before one can reasonably say it's an "intrinsic" issue. Lots of things that was considered irreducible in the past *have been* reduced.

Comment: @Dcleve You're also going to need a citation for your implicit claim that the limitation of reduction has been "accepted" across every other scientific field you know of. That's a very dubious claim. Most of science is the applicable of reductionism. We've reduced complex organisms down to molecules. We've reduced hurricanes down to weather patterns. We've reduced stars down to chemical processes. Accepting a limit of reductionism sounds like giving up. Also, if memory, emotion and reasoning are all "unconscious" functions ... what exactly is "conscious" functions then?

Comment: @NotThatGuy From section 5:  "The mainstream in the philosophy of mind is, apparently, one version or another of non-reductive physicalism. The majority within the philosophy of science has nowadays abandoned the unificationist program, to which reduction was intimately connected right from the start."  I pointed you to this in my answer.  Rationalizations that the failures of reduction are only temporary, are rejected by the majority opinion in philosophy of science.  You can deny the clear words, but they are still there.

Comment: @Dcleve It can hardly be called a "rationalization" to suppose that the phenomenon of consciousness is *not* fundamentally different from every other phenomenon in the natural world, and given that we've reduced the brain/mind so far already, that there may not be an irreducible part beyond physics particles. But okay, maybe this view isn't as widespread among naturalists as I thought. There is an understandable strong emotional appeal to thinking humans are fundamentally special, however little logical sense that makes. Uncomfortable truths are harder to swallow.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- While multiple people in the field of consciousness claim to have characterized, solved, or reduced consciousness, these are diverse and incompatible solutions, and there is a consensus among their peers that these solutions are NOT achieved.  And the recognition that reduction does not apply to everything is a near consensus among philosophers of science today.  What you, and other dogmatic material reductionists assert IS to try change how methodological naturalism works, and reject out of hand any hypothesis that does not reduce to the physical.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- So no, there is nothing "special" being assumed by spiritual dualism, emergent dualism, idealism, neutral monism, or any of the other alternatives to reductive physicalism.  The special pleading is by the reductive physicalists.  The motives for this special pleading --- yes are likely discomfort over uncomfortable truths.

Comment: @Dcleve So much of that is wrong and a strawman. I don't know who claims to have "solved" consciousness, but you'd be denying extensive amounts of evidence if you deny that we've "reduced the brain/mind so far already" (i.e. what I actually said). You've also fundamentally failed to grasp what methodological (and philosophical) naturalism is, and how the burden of proof works, if you think it's a "change" to not accept some vague supernatural explanation that we have no evidence for, or to not accept that something can't be reduced further, when it's been reduced so far already.

Comment: @Dcleve I like how you tried to throw my "discomfort over uncomfortable truths" back at me, while completely failing to in any way explain why it might be uncomfortable. Maybe you weren't able to explain that, because deep down you realise that "humans are not fundamentally special" would be a much more uncomfortable truth than "something non-physical exists" or "there is a(nother) irreducible thing".

Comment: @Dcleve There may be some discomfort in accepting that we may never be able to fully understand something, but that's the reality of every scientist - we don't understand something ... until we do. If you've ever watched any atheism/theism debate, you'd know it's usually the anti-science and dogmatically religious crowd who refuse to accept "we don't know" as an explanation (i.e. to refuse to accept that we don't know how consciousness reduces, therefore it **must** be unable to).

Comment: @Dcleve I also see you haven't bothered to answer my question: "if memory, emotion and reasoning are all 'unconscious' functions ... what exactly is 'conscious' functions then?". So not only are you claiming that some part of the brain/mind is irreducible and/or supernatural (without evidence), you also can't even define which part of the brain/mind that is. You're just appealing to some vague notion of "consciousness", that apparently excludes memory, emotion and reasoning.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- You have gone very far off topic for comments.  Further discussion belongs in a chat room.  I have created one here.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145827/discussion-on-naturalism-answers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this view that only atoms exist is mainstream, and it is wrong for many reasons.

You are correct that intentional phenomenological structures form wholes that cannot be reduced to atoms. As far as this being fringe / mainstream, it depends on what area of philosophy you deal with. In phenomenology it is mainstream, and in anglo-american analytic philosophy it is fringe.

Very few people realize that the concept of atoms is contradictory. A-tom comes from the greek for "a" (negation) - "tome" (to cut). An atom is that which cannot further be dissected. Yet, this supposedly indivisible unit is made up of neutrons, protons and quarks.

Atoms are supposed to be independent little balls that would exist if the rest of the universe did not exist, and then they say that they are actually wave functions, and those wave functions interact with other wave functions. So atoms are not really independent balls, they are non-physical wave functions.

Therefore, and atom is an indivisible divisible thing, and it is matter that is not actually matter, which is nonsense. Atoms as little bouncy balls do not exist.

Comment: "the concept of atoms is contradictory. A-tom comes from the greek..." - uhh... the word we use for a concept is largely unrelated from whether or not the underlying concept is contradictory. That point would fall apart if we use "flarglebargle" to refer to what "atom" refers to now. "Atoms are supposed to be ..., and then they say that they are actually ..." - I'd suggest taking any concerns you have over the supposed contradictions in physics, and directing those to physicists. In any case, we model reality as accurately as we can. If you have better physics models, proposals are welcome.

Comment: I think pretending that naturalism was based on an oxymoronic concept and therefore nonsense is building a strawman and a weak one at that. Show me a contemporary naturalistic philosopher who is ontologically bound to having atoms in this literal sense (or even at all) as the ultimate building blocks of reality.

Comment: This answer seems to conflate the philosophical concept of atoms with the objects chemists have decided to call atoms.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking
I think Ladyman and Ross have something close to the extreme view I mentioned, but throwing that out there is a mistake. I agree that what I called the "strict naturalist" view is not what most philosophers that would call themselves naturalists believe (that's why I called it an "extreme" form). I *do* think many naturalists would be willing to call intentionality and norms convenient fictions. Others would say they are real but reducible to natural which doesn't sound right to me but that is a more complicated matter